# textswitcher change default fade

Tags: android

I using this code to create a textswitcher, I'd like set by values a different time of fade. How I create other xml to set several fade?

```
mSwitcher = (TextSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.switcher);
mSwitcher.setFactory(this);
Animation in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,android.R.anim.fade_in);
Animation out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,android.R.anim.fade_out);
mSwitcher.setInAnimation(in);
mSwitcher.setOutAnimation(out);
```

Answer (score 2):

make a folder called `anim` inside of your project `res` folder. Add some XML files to it like this:

**fadin.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
       android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" android:duration="300" />
```

**fadout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
       android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0" android:duration="300" />
```

Change these lines in your java:

```
Animation in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,android.R.anim.fade_in);
Animation out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,android.R.anim.fade_out);
```

to be like this:

```
Animation in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.fadein);
Animation out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.fadeout);
```

Tweak the values in the xml file to make the fade appear as you want.